# How to automate get time zone detail and daylight availability

Tags: powershell, shell, windows-server

How to automate get time zone detail and daylight availability

this is my code but did not work :

```
$servers = "server1", "server2", "server3" # Replace with the names of the servers you want to query

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Write-Host "Time zone details for $server:"
    $timezone = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TimeZone -ComputerName $server
    $timezone | Select-Object Caption, StandardName, DaylightName, Bias
    Write-Host ""
}
```

and the response is below:

```
At line:4 char:39
+     Write-Host "Time zone details for $server:"
+                                       ~~~~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the 
name.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell has special handling of semicolons after variables: it assumes the part preceding it to be a [drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/managing-windows-powershell-drives?view=powershell-7.3) and expects something to follow.

In this case you should modify your string so it interpolates properly:

```
Write-Host "Time zone details for $($server):"
```